# How to add spaces between column in R?

Tags: sql, r, text-files, space

I am needing to add a certain amount of spaces between a column in my dataset.

I am using RODBC and sqlquery function and my script generates out a txt file with fixed widths using write.fwf.

I have one column where I had to create a separate dataframe variable and replace the old column with this new variable, and ever since I replaced it, I can't seem to adjust its width anymore.

I've tried going into my sqlquery and adding '      ' spaces to the column before the one I replaced but the text file still comes out with no spacing between them. The reason I replaced the column was because I needed to format it to show trailing zeros.

Before, my columns were like this:

```
Column1         Column2
A               20
```

Now after replacing the column, it looks like this in the text file:

```
Column1 Column2
A       20.00
```

Is there any way that I can readjust the width or spacing between the two columns compared to how it was before I did the replacement?

Comment: look at `gdata::write.fwf()` to write fixed width files.

Comment: Can you please add examples of the code you have written for this to help answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way to do this.

I created another dataframe in another variable with just that column and used paste() to include the blank spaces in front of the column, and then replaced the column in the dataset with this newly created variable.

```
ColumnSpaced <- data.frame("Column2" = paste("    ", Table1$Column2))
table$Column2 <- ColumnSpaced$Column2
```